# Using list comprehension for finding 1 element in a list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a quick question regarding best practices for Python. I've seen where lambda + filter functions were used over list comprehension, but I wanted to know if there's an easier way for finding a specific element in a list without the need to generate and iterate throughout the entire list.

Using the AWS boto3 library, I'm querying various get_x() functions by using list comprehension:

`[i['domainName'] for i in domain_names['items'] if re.search(r'\b'+domain_name, i['domainName'])].pop()`

`[i['id'] for i in usage_plans['items'] if i['name']==f'{self.service}Usage'].pop()`

If there isn't an item found, an IndexError will be captured and relayed back to the user. Since this is in an AWS Lambda function, I'm worried about scalability and runtime billing for the function.

Should I keep using the list comprehension the way I'm going about it, or is there a better way?

Comment: You can always go imperative way and just write out the function.

Comment: Definitely, but I just didn't know if there was a quick and one-off way of doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to avoid iterating through the entire list, you can use a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension. For example:

```
next(i for i in range(0, 2**1000) if i % 2 == 1)
```

Iterating through that entire range will take a while, but using the generator comprehension it's instantaneous.

Note that if it doesn't find an item you get a `StopIteration` exception instead of the `IndexError`. You really **must** catch that and wrap it in another exception, because a stray `StopIteration` propagating through the stack may cause weird behavior.

Wrapping the `StopIteration` looks like this:

```
>>> try:
...   next(i for i in range(0, 100) if i % 2 == 3 )
... except StopIteration:
...   raise IndexError("Couldn't find item")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: Couldn't find item
```

Note that you can give `next` a default value to return instead of raising `StopIteration`:

```
>>> print(next((i for i in range(0, 100) if i % 2 == 3), None))
None
```

Comment: That latter comment is worth 10 upvotes, the time I once spent debugging a loop that mysteriously finished early because some entirely unrelated next() deep in a call stack didn't catch it...

Comment: Honestly, this is why I love stackoverflow. Thanks cha0site, I'll most likely accept this as answer, but I'm going to leave it open just for a bit longer. I definitely appreciate the response!

Comment: Quick question on that though, how would your wrap a `StopIteration` exception?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor: I added some info about that.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank you so much for your time @cha0site